# how to customize file content using Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am generating a txt file using angularjs.  I have some problem with data inside the file, this is a small snippet of my code :

```
var fileContent =  ["text line 1","text line 2","text line 3","text line 4","text line 5","text line 6"];
var blob = new Blob([ fileContent ], { type : 'text/plain' });
$scope.url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL( blob );
```

html :

```
<a download="file.txt" ng-href="{{ url }}">download</a>
```

the result in the file is :

text line 1,text line 2,text line 3,text line 4,text line 5,text line 6

I want to show the result as follows : 
text line 1 
text line 2 
text line 3 
text line 4 
text line 5 
text line 6

I want to show each element in the array on one line and without ","

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `replace` function as follows:

```
var resultFile = "text line 1,text line 2,text line 3,text line 4,text line 5,text line 6";
var newOutput = x.replace(/,/g, "\n");
```

The `newOutput` value should be:

```
text line 1
text line 2
text line 3
text line 4
text line 5
text line 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape a new line.  `"text line 1" + \n`

Do this:

```
var fileStr = fileContent.join("\n");
```

Comment: thank you for your response, it works fine , but i still have problem with "," how to remove them from the file?

Comment: If you did join `join("\n")` correctly... You shouldn't have any commas.

Comment: thank you brother for the response , i solved my problem (y)